# how to know the value of a checkbox using ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have a form and before I submit this form I want to do something based on a checkbox if its selected or not.

this is my checkbox :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="resident" id="resident"
               ng-model="resident" ng-init="resident=false">
```

in my controller I have this :

```
    $scope.submitForm = function (isValid) {

    if(!$scope.resident){
                //code...
    }else{
                //code...
    }

}
```

but then I always get the value of this checkbox as undefined even though I have initialized it to `false`.

I don't want to work with `ng-change`  since I only need to know the value for the checkbox and not to do treatments whenever it changed.

how can I solve this ?

Comment: value attribute is missing from input

Comment: @AnkurTiwari I've attached the attribute value but I still have the same problem

Comment: @DushyantBangal it always prints undefined

Comment: yes, sorry you had already specified that one in question.

Comment: are you using it inside `ng-if` or `ng-switch` ?

Comment: @DushyantBangal no I didn't I have solved the problem using the batrang tool, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have attached to the question does not contain any issue. The issue is some where else in the code that you have not posted here. Refer below code it does work.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
  
  <input type="checkbox" name="resident" id="resident"
           ng-model="resident" ng-init="resident=false">{{resident}}
  
</div>
```

Possible issue:
Refer to the Scope that is attached to the input checkbox sometimes happens that variable or model has been in parent scope and we are trying to manipulate in child scope. Use chrome tool like [batrang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) that can guide you better with respect to the child and parent scope inspection.

Comment: using that tool helped me figuring out what was the problem thanks

Answer (score 1):

View:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="resident" id="resident" ng-model="resident.checked">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.resident = {
   checked: false;
}
```

That's it! The model will automatically switch from `false` to `true` via the `ng-model` directive.
See http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2989/

Comment: It's worth adding that It's generally bad practice to use ng-init. This is because the view is initialized at a different time than the controller AND the digest cycle has to process that function, which is an unnecessary addition to the cycle.